# Converting plain string to JSON

Tags: java, jersey, jackson

The service below:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response getJson(...) {
    return Response.ok("hello").build();
}
```

should return `application/json`.

However, the call to this service returns with

```
Status-Code: 200
Content-Type:application/json
Response: hello
```

Shouldn't it throw some kind of Exception during the serialization of a plain string into JSON, because "hello" isn't a valid JSON?

Any ideas why this works?

Comment: return type is application/json. It doesn't say to return only JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no connection between the `Content-Type` and the response itself.

Java does not make any provision or validation of the data returned.

The `Content-Type` is primary for the client to determine the content type but for the server it is only a string sent to the client.

What the client does when the `Content-Type` and the real content do not match is up to the client.

Also there is no *serialization* done by Java but the returned value is sent plain to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If that's correct I don't see how `@Produces` is related to the Response then. So far I assumed that if the above service is called it can only return a valid application/json when the client requests application/json.

Comment: @akoskm The annotation is for documentation and to set the `Content-Type` of the reply. Nothing more.

Comment: so basically it's possible to create a web service where the content and the content type returned are totally unrelated to each other. Thank you for the clarification!